# Tomcat9 on Fedora29: 403 on webapps

Tags: tomcat, fedora

I have edit

```
/etc/tomcat/context.xml

<Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="\d+\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+" /
```

Probably not necessary,but I also restart tomcat

```
systemctl restart tomcat
```

Now go on browser and...403

What I miss?
System is Fedora 29 server,with latest tomcat9

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution found,the file to edit is

```
/var/lib/tomcat/webapps/manager/META-INF/context.xml
```

and a good line to allow localhost+your ip(192.168.0.2 in my case)

```
<Context antiResourceLocking="false" privileged="true" >
  <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.RemoteAddrValve"
         allow="127\.\d+\.\d+\.\d+|::1|0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1|192.168.0.2" />
  <Manager sessionAttributeValueClassNameFilter="java\.lang\.(?:Boolean|Integer|Long|Number|String)|org\.apache\.catalina\.filters\.CsrfPreventionFilter\$LruCache(?:\$1)?|java\.util\.(?:Linked)?HashMap"/>
</Context>
```

Restart tomcat and will ask the password for the admin or the user you define in `/etc/tomcat/tomcat-users.xml`